# Laço não executa tudo o que deveria

Tags: c, loop

Estou com um problema no meu programa, preciso que ele mostre aleatoriamente uma ordem de números (equipes). O problema é que quando eu coloco um número maior que 10 ele não mostra os 10, mostra somente alguns:

```
   int cont1, aux, n, sorteio;
    char op = 's';



setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

do{
    printf("Digite a quintidade de equipes para serem sorteadas: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

    int matriz[2][n];

    for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < n; cont1++){
        matriz[1][cont1] = cont1 + 1;
        matriz[2][cont1] = cont1 + 1;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < n; cont1++){
        sorteio = rand() % n;
        aux = matriz[2][cont1];
        matriz[2][cont1] = matriz[2][sorteio];
        matriz[2][sorteio] = aux;

    }

    for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < n; cont1++){
        printf("Linha 1 da MATRIZ - Ordem das Apresentações: %d   |   ", matriz[1][cont1]);
        printf("Linha 2 da MATRIZ - Número da Equipe: %d", matriz[2][cont1]);
        printf("\n");

    }
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("Deseja realizar outro sorteio? (S/N)> ");

    fflush(stdin);

    op = getchar();

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

}while((op == 'S') | (op == 's'));

}
```

Comment: Você declarou  int matriz[2][n]; e portanto o primeiro índice deve ser 0 ou 1 e não 1 ou 2 como utilizou.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é o acesso ao *array*. Você está acessando os índice 1 e 2 do *array*, ma ele só vai até o índice 1. *arrays* começam em 0. Note que na coluna você está fazendo certo, já que o laço começa em 0, mas na linha está começando em 1, então uma das dimensões não está sendo inicializada, e isso não é problema, porque ela nunca é acessada mesmo, mas quando tenta escrever no índice 2 que não tem memória reservada para ele acaba passando por cima de outras áreas da memória reservadas para outra coisa e aí o número de controle, no caso `n` acaba sendo alterado sem querer. Assim está correto e mais organizado (dá para melhorar mais):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    char op = 's';
    do {
        printf("Digite a quantidade de equipes para serem sorteadas: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        int matriz[2][n];
        for (int cont1 = 0; cont1 < n; cont1++) {
            matriz[0][cont1] = cont1 + 1;
            matriz[1][cont1] = cont1 + 1;
        }
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int cont1 = 0; cont1 < n; cont1++) {
            int sorteio = rand() % n;
            int aux = matriz[1][cont1];
            matriz[1][cont1] = matriz[1][sorteio];
            matriz[1][sorteio] = aux;
        }
        for (int cont1 = 0; cont1 < n; cont1++) {
            printf("Linha 1 da MATRIZ - Ordem das Apresentações: %d   |   ", matriz[0][cont1]);
            printf("Linha 2 da MATRIZ - Número da Equipe: %d\n", matriz[1][cont1]);
        }
        printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
        printf("Deseja realizar outro sorteio? (S/N)> ");
        op = getchar();
        printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    } while (op == 'S' || op == 's');
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/X1jsMh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kqeylmnz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/IndexOffsetZero.c).

Comment: Seu diagnóstico estaria certo 30 anos atrás. O mais provável é que, como compiladores modernos assumem que não ocorre comportamento indefinido no seu código, as otimizações viram que os laços for acessam um lugar inexistente, causando UB. Então, o compilador conclui que é impossível que esses laços executem. Mas até isso pode mudar com o tempo. De qualquer maneira, o diagnóstico tecnicamente correto é: "acesso fora dos limites causa comportamento indefinido e, após isso, todo o seu programa é renderizado inútil e qualquer coisa pode acontecer."

Comment: E está errado agora? Mostre o erro. Estou ajudando uma pessoa com um problema, não estou escrevendo uma tese.

Comment: Maniero, eu apenas quis dizer que os motivos podem ser vários devido ao avanço nas otimizações de compiladores. Você citou um de muitos possíveis efeitos colaterais como sendo o único possível. Por exemplo, mostrando a saída sem e com otimizações, vemos o efeito que UB causa no programa: https://godbolt.org/z/ODncL2 Eu acredito que respostas tecnicamente corretas são mais úteis, porque várias pessoas vão acabar lendo essa thread.